# How to enable anonyms access for AKS Custer?

Tags: azure-aks

I need to enable 1000+ users access to AKS cluster.

I tried to update clusterrole and clusterrolebinding but it doesn't fix my problem.

Comment: This is a major security risk, AKS apiserver is a public endpoint (unless you are using a private AKS cluster), and having anonymous access means anyone on the internet has access to your cluster.

That being said, you always need authentication/authorization with any k8s api server. 

The easiest (totally not recommended) thing to do, is to share the k8s configfile with your users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think AKS provides you with a feature of anonymous access.

That being said, using Azure Kubernetes Service provides you with added advantages such as RBAC with Azure AD. This can help you out. You can find more in here,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/concepts-identity